# how to use as sentence in rails ActiveRecord query interface

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For example, how to represent

```
select id from users as u,teachers as t where u.id = t.id
```

through the relevant api. 
    And I want a ActiveRecord::relation object as the result.

Comment: what other methods you are talking about you want to chain?

Comment: other methods is not fixed. With a relation as the result, I can decompose my api into many small functions and combine them flexibly. If the result is not a relation, it seems not convenient.

Comment: then you better fix that first, because every result would be an object of some class which will support few methods and few not. If you are looking for `scope` chaining, then you need active record query. chalk out your requirements..

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like

```
sql = "Select id from ... your sql query here"
record= ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: But this will return a result object rather than relation. I can chain other method to relation while result is not allowed